# How to save WhatsApp voice messages

Tags: whatsapp, messaging

How can I save received WhatsApp voice messages or where are they stored?

btw: my platform is Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: if you tap+hold on a voice message, what options does it give (if any) ?

Comment: Delete and Forward

Comment: Check if it is stored in whatsapp's media folder..Am not sure of that

Answer (score 2):

With the latest update of WhatsApp, you can store and send audio files.
Go to,
SD card> picture > WhatsApp
There you will find that audio file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [web.whatsapp.com](http://web.whatsapp.com), scroll up to your voice message play it and grab it using any tool.

Answer (score 1):

You tap the message you want to save so it turns blue, tap share, email it to yourself and store it wherever you want...simples.

Comment: This does not provide the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot store the voice messages with the current Whatsapp version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked `Save Incoming Media` under your WhatsApp settings, and you have already downloaded/listened to the voice notes, they will be in your device under **`Storage > Pictures > Whatsapp > PTT`**, or in the mother folder of the PTT folder, that is, the WhatsAp folder under Pictures.